# Why doesn't ellipsometry measure optical constants directly?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

Why does [ellipsometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsometry) aim to build a model of a sample that reproduces the experimental data $\psi$ and $\Delta$, which are often defined by the total reflection coefficients,
$$\frac{r_p}{r_s}=e^{i\Delta}\tan\psi,$$
instead of calculating the optical constants and thicknesses constituting the sample from the experimental data directly?

From my understanding (and I may be wrong) it is possible to calculate the optical constants and thicknesses of the various layers directly from experimental data, assuming everything is ideal and measurements are made at enough angles of incidence. For instance, for a simple air-substrate system, we have: $$\epsilon=\sin^2\phi_0\left[1+\left(\frac{1-e^{i\Delta}\tan\psi}{1+e^{i\Delta}\tan\psi}\right)^2\tan^2\phi_0\right],$$
where $\epsilon$ is the complex dielectric function of the substrate, and $\phi_0$ is the angle of incidence.

I was not able to find any information that directly addressed my question in any textbooks or online, so I would greatly appreciate your insights on this. If anything needs clarifying, please let me know.

EDIT:

A comprehensive answer to my question is given in section 4.5 of "*Ellipsometry and Polarized Light*" by Azzam and Bashara.

From my understanding, it is often possible to obtain the optical properties of a sample from $\psi$ and $\Delta$ using numerical techniques. Obtaining an analytic solution to the set of simultaneous equations relating the optical properties of the sample to $\psi$ and $\Delta$ given $\psi$ and $\Delta$ is often not possible as the equations in the set are usually nonlinear and transcendental in nature. In cases where an analytic solution can be obtained, a least squares solution is often needed anyways due to possible errors in the experimental data/model. This is why, again, from my understanding, optical constants aren't directly extracted from $\psi$ and $\Delta$.

It is not explicitly stated why numerically solving the set of equations given $\psi$ and $\Delta$ is not preferred over building a model that closely reproduces the experimental $\psi$ and $\Delta$ (my understanding of computer science and numerical methods is poor). I assume that the latter is computationally cheaper than the former, hence why the latter is the more stand method in the field of ellipsometry.

A lot of this is outside of my circle of competence, so if there is anything wrong with my reasoning, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a homogenous material with a mirror-polished surface, your unknowns are the pair of optical constants. With your two knowns ($\Psi$ and $\Delta$), you can find the two optical constants directly and uniquely.

Otherwise, you need a model that includes inputs that don't come from the optical data. Even if you knew the materials, and hence the optical constants, and the order of stacking, you might not know their thicknesses. This is something that is not directly extractable from the data. These need to be input or fit to match your data.

From my experience, Woollam is a big player, if not the biggest, in ellipsometers. They have great tutorials and faq: https://www.jawoollam.com/